# Make SQLite datafiles to be locked on OS level

Tags: c#, windows, sqlite

We need to lock our SQLite datafiles at the filesystem level, because our application frequently crashes with "database is locked" error, which is probably due to other processes opening our files. At least we identified (and fixed) Windows Search indexing the files but there must be more.

I have tried exclusive locking mode by

```
PRAGMA locking_mode=EXCLUSIVE;
```

but this does not prevent reading and modifying the file from other process.

After digging in SQLite sources it seems not possible. VFS for Windows [always sends](https://www.sqlite.org/src/artifact/7f36120492e4a23c) these share mode flags to [`CreateFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx).

```
dwShareMode = FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE;
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: There is no workaround on the Windows level -- you can't open the file again in exclusive mode, you can't lock the file without making the original handle inaccessible, and you can change the ACL to give exclusive access, but this will only lock out processes belonging to other users (like Windows Search, but not other software the user runs). Changing the VFS seems like the only viable option. Note that there is a `unix-excl` VFS that does exactly this, there just doesn't seem to be one for Windows (but it would be fairly easy to write).

Comment: Have you set a busy timeout?

Comment: @CL.: We have busy timeout set but I found out some applications even modify our datafiles (McAffee antivirus).